# jakewharton Espresso Idling Resource won't import

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-espresso, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm writing tests using okhttp3, mockwebserver, and retrofit2 in Android/Kotlin.

Everything I look up tells me to use the jakewharton idling resource, but it will not import into my project.

[image: screenshot]

I got the info straight from Jake Wharton's [github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource)

Screenshot of my build.gradle
[image: build.gradle]

1. Is there anything I can do to fix this?
2. Are there decent alternatives to adding this type of idle resource to my test suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `build.gradle` dependencies no longer support `androidTestCompile`.

The dependency should switch from:

`androidTestCompile 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'`

to

`androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'`